# Render GPS - LocationSensor on static map in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, app-inventor

I need some guidance to have the current location or GPS (lat & long), displayed on a WebViewer static map with App Inventor 2.
I have created a static map api and I'm trying to follow and modify this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mitappinventortest/WgINCL3oP2c/lOf4c4QoMysJ), found at app inventor google forum.

In particular, I cannot modify what user SteveGS suggested, to have the center of static map rendered always to the current values of latitude and longitude from the LocationSensor, instead of a hard coded lat and long. 
I have tried the following block combination without success:

[image]

Can someone help me out, in order to have LocationSensor marker or GPS on this static map api? Thank you all in advance for your answers.

-Edit 1-

Have tried the following blocks to get the hard coded Lat and Long of the original google forums post (see link), modified with LocationSensor readings through the use of two variables, as suggested. Unfortunately, instead of e.g. having the position marker displayed on Italy, I got the static map displayed centered in Mauritania. What is wrong with this code? See following image:

[image]

Comment: if you have a question about an example from *SteveJG*, why don't you ask him in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest) instead? Btw: does it make sense to use 2 different accelerometer sensors? It also helps to use **Do it** to debug your blocks, in your case the URL of the webviewer...

Comment: Hello @Taifun, nice to hear from you again. Never though of asking SteveJG, since I'm not very familiar with App Inventor forum, as I am to S.O. It is an old thread at the forum, so it is kind weird to resurrect

Comment: Anyway @Taifun, I'm using two Accelerometers to read yAccel and zAccel respectively. Since I don't get any errors, is it o.k. to keep them both? Regarding my initial question, I think I'm getting somewhere... On second thought, it sees I need to have the Internet - WiFi connection and GPS enabled in 5 minute intervals to reduce data cost. So, how can this be done in App Inventor 2? Can you help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official demo `Android, Where's My Car?` [here](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/android-wheres-my-car.html), you can try following:

`LocationSensor1.LocationChanged`: This event occurs `when the phone's location sensor first gets a reading`, or `when the phone is moved to produce a new reading`. The event-handler just places the readings--`latitude, longitude, and current (street) address`-- into the corresponding `Current` labels so that they appear on the phone.

[image]

Also, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugWu3gyte4I&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSKgnFm8-6Fz1cd6zt_KxTC) is whole episodes to teach you how to make an app by using `App inventor 2`.

Comment: Thank you @bjiang for your answer and suggested links to tutorials. Need to mention though, that I need to have the LocationSensor marked position on a static map with or without GPS enabled. Furthermore, I need to update the LocationSensor marker on static map in intervals as having a live position of the user lat and long. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean use the network to get the user location?

Comment: yes, LocationSensor can be used with network too. My initial scope for this app was to have it mark position with GPS and LocationSensor for maximum accuracy. Take a look at my edit, cause I'm trying to get current location through variables and instead of Italy I got static map centerer to Mauritania. What is wrong with my blocks?

Comment: thanks for the link, already tried it, not the functionality I need. To sum up, I want to show in a WebViewer not in a new activity screen, the LocationSensor marker on a static google map. If this can be done using only GPS it would be great.